# Error 2203 During Installation of Custom MSI on Multiple Machines: Troubleshooting

Tags: c#, windows-installer

We encountered an issue while installing the MSI using the following command:

```
msiexec /i localMSI.msi /qn /L*V localMSI.log
```

The installation process displayed an error message stating:

> "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2203."

Upon investigation, we found that the msiexec process was running and had created a file named "inprogressinstallinfo.ipi" which it was unable to delete. Killing the msiexec task allowed the installation to proceed successfully. This issue was encountered on multiple machines.

It's important to note that the MSI was created by us using C# code, and we are attempting to install it on different machines.

---

Here is a snippet from the localMSI.log:

```
MSI (s) (C0:94) [23:59:22:166]: Server not locked: locking for product {186ADC86-B01C-4320-8850-AF1EB2322259} 
MSI (s) (C0:94) [23:59:22:166]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287008  
MSI (s) (C0:94) [23:59:22:166]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038  
Action start 23:59:22: InstallInitialize. 
DEBUG: Error 2203: Database: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi. Cannot open database file. System error -2147287008 
MSI (s) (C0:94) [23:59:22:182]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038  
MSI (s) (C0:94) [23:59:22:182]: Product: localMSI -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2203. The arguments are: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi, -2147287008. 
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2203. The arguments are: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi, -2147287008.  
Action ended 23:59:22: InstallInitialize. Return value 3. 
Action ended 23:59:22: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

#### What we tried:

- Attempted to install the MSI using the provided command: `msiexec /i DotNetInterfaceInstaller.msi /qn /L*V DotNetInterfaceReInstall.log`.
- Investigated the issue and discovered that the msiexec process was running and had created an "inprogressinstallinfo.ipi" file, which it was unable to delete.
- Killed the msiexec task to allow the installation to proceed successfully.

#### What we expected:

- Expected the MSI installation to complete without encountering any errors.
- Anticipated that the installation process would run smoothly on multiple machines, as the MSI was created by our team and intended for deployment.

Comment: did you run the MSI as adminstrator? Does the SYSTEM account has permissions: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-fix-internal-error-2203/9fed443b-aadd-4f92-a642-74162ee2c0fd

Comment: Yes, I tried running MSI as administrator using msiexec. As right click run as admin option was not available.  Yes system account has permissions as well.